Global value is not initalized
I have a global variable User? current_atlas_user that is in file 'Constants.dart'. I want to initialize it from the main.dart file.
To do it I am trying this:
Future<void> setAtlasUser(String email) async {
  final app = App(AppConfiguration(APP_ID));
  current_atlas_user =
      await app.logIn(Credentials.emailPassword(email, ATLAS_PASSWD));
}

This function is called in the end of the @override void initState() function. And after using the debugger I made sure that the code is reaching the Future<void> setAtlasUser(String email) function.
My problem is here
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> _screens = [NotDoneScreen(), const DoneScreen()];

The NotDoneScreen() assumes that current_atlas_user is already defined. But when running the code it fails saying that it is still null.
I know that initState() should run before build() and therefore I am confused about this problem.

initState is run before build, but your initState does asynchronous work that is not guaranteed to be complete by the time build is called.  You must ensure that you wait for your asynchronous operations to complete first.  This is why you should use a FutureBuilder.

You can use FutureBuilder to wait for current_atlas_user to initialize. While waiting for future to finish, you can show some sort of loading indicator. Here is how I would structure it:

create a local variable to store the future:

Future<void>? _current_atlas_user_future;


assign value to local variable in initState

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _current_atlas_user_future = setAtlasUser(email);
  }


now add FutureBuilder to build method


@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<void>(
       future: _current_atlas_user_future,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                 // current_atlas_user should be ready here
                 // load the screens
                 List<Widget> _screens = [NotDoneScreen(), const DoneScreen()];

            } else {
                 // current_atlas_user should be null here

                // show some sort of loading indicator
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
        }
    );
}

Note that _current_atlas_user_future  is separate from current_atlas_user . _current_atlas_user_future is just holding reference to a future and current_atlas_user is the value you need in your next screen.
